# Should Be Simply Bash Script - But I Can't Get It to Work Correctly

Tags: bash, directory, find, move, exit

I'm trying to create an Automation tied to a calendar event on my Mac.  It is to run a bash script on a daily basis.

What I am trying and failing is getting it to recognize an if else fi process.  Basically, I am asking it to first check to see if there are any files in the folder identified.  If there are none (no files in the folder), I want it to exit the script.  If there are files in the folder I want to move them to a different folder.

I've tried many iterations of the find function (I'll paste the most recent below).  So, I start with some m4a files in the folder.  I run the script below and it successfully moves the files to the folder I want them moved to.  I run the script a second time (now the folder is empty because I just moved all of the files out of it).  The second run was just me testing to see if the script is recognizing the folder is empty and exits the script.  However, the folder is empty and I get an error message that appears that the script tried to run the move (mv) again - which to me seems like it is ignoring the "if" check.

Here is what I have:

```
cd /Users/mikehaddon/Desktop/Network/BOPPAudioWork/M4AHoldingBin

if find /Users/mikehaddon/Desktop/Network/BOPPAudioWork/M4AHoldingBin -empty | read; then

    exit

else

    mv -f *.m4a /Users/mikehaddon/Desktop/BOPPAudio

fi
```

Pretty basic.  Look in the folder.  If it is empty, exit the script.  If it isn't empty, move the folder's contents to a different location.

Pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if folder is empty like this:

```
if [ -z "$(ls -A /path/to/folder)" ]; then
  #
  # Folder is empty, exit script
  exit 0
else
  #
  # Folder contains something
  # do your stuff and exit... 
  mv /path/to/folder/* /target/folder
  exit 0
fi
```

If you want to check and copy only specific files based on their extensions, you can do it this way:

```
if ls /path/to/folder/*.m4a > /dev/null 2>&1; then
  #
  # m4a files founded, move and exit
  mv /path/to/folder/*.m4a /target/folder
  exit 0
else
  #
  # No *.m4a files, exit
  exit 0
fi
```